# How to find out ImageViews or ImageButtons on screen using resource ID? - Robotium

Tags: android, robotium, android-resources

Scenario: Home screen contains <kbd>Menu</kbd> button at top left, top right has Search icon. On screen application displays 10 images, say under Album/Songs tag.

As told by developer, only 1 image/resource is displayed and is then duplicated to display other 9 images.

I want to automate:

- Whether home screen contains 10 images under Albums tag or not?
- How do I find the images using `R.id` of Robotium?
- Do I need to include in build path of my test project to get access to those resources on screen?

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through all the children of your view.

```
int childcount = yourView.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
    View v = yourView.getChildAt(i);
    // Now here you can check if v is an image..
}
```

hope i have understood your question!

Comment: Sorry. I did not get you. On home screen of my app, I have- Menu icon top left, search icon top right, and 9 images are displayed on home screen. Now the problem is if I use this method >>
ArrayList<ImageView> imgViews= new ArrayList<ImageView> ();
     imgViews=solo.getCurrentImageViews();
What I get is all current views of solo. So I get Menu icon, search icon and so many other image views in it.  
How do I find / differentiate from this array where exactly the 9 images start counting? Can I directly refer/check if 9 images are displayed or not on home screen?

Comment: Every ImageView is indexed in Solo. Generally views are indexed from top left corner to bottom right corner, so you can easily count, which indexes are searched.

You can also assert size of solo.getCurrentImageViews(), if it shouldn't change in your application, but you have to count all of the images.